# Connecting an accelerometer to a microcontroller pull up voltages

Tags: accelerometer, microcontroller

Im trying to connect a MMA852Q accellerometer to a 18F2550 microcontroller. According to accellerometer datasheet i2c clock and data lines would not tolerate voltages more than 1.6- 3.7 (+0.3). Those lines have to be pulled up to 5v for microcntroller to work.  Im new in to this subject and your advice to overcome this issue would be really helpful.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stackoverflow. However your question seems more belonging to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could look for "[I2C level shifter](http://www.i2c-bus.org/level-shifting/)" for attaching buses with different voltages together.

[NXP appnote 10441 (pdf)](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10441.pdf) has a very neat generic one, for example.